# Check Role Permission Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a function that has a for loop that checks for a user roles:

`for role in ctx.author.roles:`

Now, I want to check if "role" has the permission Manage_Channels

Thanks for the helpers!!!

Comment: Do you need that to block non admins from using the command ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to check if the author has a permission to use the command. There is a bulit-in function to do that [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions).

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You can manage channels.')
```

for the error message

```py
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

@test.error
async def test_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you do not have permissions to do that!')
```

Comment: Where? I couldn't find it

Comment: There is a link marked with `Docs` This is the example from there, try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: what you wrote is right, but if the author doesnt have permissions, then the bot wont send any message, I want it to send a message if the author doesnt have permissions

Comment: it doesn't detect the error I think, here is what I've change:

Comment: ```@clear.error
async def clear_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you do not have permissions to do that!')```